# Calculate Colors in between start and endcolor (lineargradient)

Tags: android, colors, gradient

in Android i have two colors integers:

```
int oldColor = getActivity().getWindow().getStatusBarColor();
int newColor = mColor;
```

now i want to fade the statusbar in between these two colors via a ValueAnimator:

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(oldColor, newColor);
animator.setDuration(200);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor((Integer)animation.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});
animator.start();
```

Now obviously this does not work, but i hope you get my intention... How would i calculate the values in between oldColor and newColor accurately with a predefined amount of steps?

Regards

//EDIT:

I have added 
`animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator())` to my code, it now works like a charm :))

Comment: Yeah just seen it as well... added animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator()) it works like a charm

Comment: well, this is what `Evaluator`s are for... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int oldColor = getActivity().getWindow().getStatusBarColor();
int newColor = mColor;
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(oldColor, newColor);
animator.setDuration(200);
animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator())
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor((Integer)animation.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});
animator.start();
```